# Horizon fails to start

Tags: django, fiware, openstack-horizon

I've followed this guide: [https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Identity_Management_-*KeyRock*-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Identity_Management_-_KeyRock_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide)

When i run the server i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named oslo.utils
```

I've tried using --pythonpath but to no avail. I've also ran ./run_tests.sh and here are the results: http://pastebin.com/6i7Ws5Ej.

System:
CentOS 6.5 x64,
python 2.6.6

Any idea how to solve this? any info i might have forgotten don’t hesitate to ask

**Edit:**
I've switched to ubuntu 12 to follow the tutorial step by step. I got keystone running but horizon still fails and gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually updating pbr to 1.3.0 directly from python and pip solved all issues

Answer (score 1):

A fix was also committed on KeyRock's Github account.

[Here](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/issues/3) is the issue.